# Haarcascading XML does not work properly

Tags: c++, xml, opencv3.0

I'm pretty new to OpenCV and cascade training. I did train a cascade to recognize "running" motion. I used Haar-like and LBP. For haar-like I used 1181 positive images and 3866 negative images and 12 stages. For LBP I used 2426 positive images and 1031 negative images and 12 staged.

Following, you could see a screenshot of each one.

[image: haar-like cascading]

[image: LBP cascading]

After a while waiting for training to be finished (around 3-4 hours for each one) I would be able to create the xml files from AdaBoost chart classifiers.
The problem is that when I use them on my code to see how they are working, they don't recognize any of obvious running motions! The code is written with C++ and OpenCV 3.3.

Does anyone have any idea why my cascade xml files after training do not working properly?

C++ code is as below:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //open from file
    VideoCapture video("../data/videos/people_activity/run/run2.mp4");
    Mat img;
    Mat frmg;

    // Load cascate classifier placed in sulution folder
    CascadeClassifier bodydetector, rundetector;
    string bodycascadeName = "haarcascade_fullbody.xml";
    string runcascadeName = "lbpcascade_run.xml";
    bool bodyloaded = bodydetector.load(bodycascadeName);
    bool runloaded = rundetector.load(runcascadeName);


    // Parameters of detectMultiscale Cascade Classifier
    int groundThreshold = 1;
    double scaleStep = 1.1;
    Size minimalObjectSize(40, 40);
    Size maximalObjectSize(200, 200);



    // Vector of returned bodies and run
    std::vector<Rect> bodyfound, runmotion;

    while (video.read(img))
    {

        // Image from video read and store to Mat
        video >> img;

        if (img.rows == 0)//end of video
            break;


        // Convert input to greyscale 
        Mat image_grey;
        cvtColor(img, image_grey, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        bodyfound.clear();



        // Detect bodies
        bodydetector.detectMultiScale(image_grey, bodyfound, scaleStep, groundThreshold, 0 | 2, minimalObjectSize, maximalObjectSize);

        for (size_t k = 0; k < bodyfound.size(); k++)
        {


            //draw a rectangle with red color around it
            rectangle(img, bodyfound[k].br(), bodyfound[k].tl(), Scalar(0, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);

            Mat bodyROI = img(bodyfound[k]);

            //Detect running for bodies if there is any!
            rundetector.detectMultiScale(bodyROI, runmotion, scaleStep, groundThreshold, 0 | 2, minimalObjectSize, maximalObjectSize);

            //if any were found!
            if (runmotion.size() > 0) {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < runmotion.size(); i++)
                {
                    //draw a rectangle with red color around it
                    rectangle(img, runmotion[i].br(), runmotion[i].tl(), Scalar(80, 0, 255), 1, 8, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        imshow("result", img);

        int c = waitKey(10);
        if ((char)c == 27) { break; } // escape

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There could be tons of pitfalls in OpenCV CC, Can you show us your code?

Comment: sure, I added it. But The code is somehow (with some acceptable errors) works for finding full bodies, using the ready haarcascade_fullbody.xml!

Comment: Hve you cross-validated your classifier?

Comment: what does that mean to cross-validate? I'm afraid I did not do any other thing than what I explained!

Comment: There could have been two major problems in your training process: 1. Bias (lack of diversity in training data or training data size, 2. Overfitting (training more than you need). You can inspect these with [K-Fold cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation) or another CV method.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think the diversity in training data could cover all possible poses for running motion. But all of my training data have the same size. Would it make some errors?

Comment: OpenCV resizes images internally, so no, I don't think dimensions matter.